# Keeping track of open windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have browser base application. I need to keep track of which windows were/are open. With the below example, I can keep track of each window and also reference it. Is variable `ow` stored by reference or by value?

```
   var openWindows = [];
   var ow = window.open('mywindow.aspx');
   openWindows.push(ow);
```

I asked because I would assume that if it stores the variable by value, this would be terrible inefficient.

Comment: In JS everything is passed by value except objects and arrays which are passed by reference.

Comment: So since `openWindows` is an array and `ow` is an object, I am good-to-go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ow` is a reference to the newly created window. You can store it in array without afraid of ineffectiveness.
You can read more info about window.open here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open